# Runtime error (dll loading) with win32 applications on x64 system, while compiling 0K

Tags: c++, dll, 64-bit, binary-compatibility, wow64

I originally designed a win32 application on win7 32bits, with VC9.0.
I recently upgraded to win7 64 bits, and tried to build+execute the previous application.

Building runs fine (win32 application), but on runtime I get the error "[...] has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b)."

I guess this results of the loading of a 64bits version of an [intended] 32bits dll.

Specific dependencies for this project are:
  SDL.lib
  SDLmain.lib
  SDL_ttf.lib
  opengl32.lib
  glu32.lib
  wininet.lib

SDL and SDL_ttf are only in 32bits version.
I assume that Visual Studio is clever enough to fetch the opengl and glu lib files in \syswow64 as I request a win32 application.

Could it be because of wininet? Or did I make a mistake?

Thanks,

Comment: You guess? So you haven't actually tried debugging it? Have you at least checked it out with Dependency Walker?

Comment: That's STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, you cannot load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process.  Cats and dogs.

Comment: Indeed it was a guess. I am quite a newbie, and not acquainted with this kind of issues. Cats and dogs, effectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears you are loading a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process or vice versa.  Here's how I would go about tracking down the offending DLL.

The first step is to run dumpbin.exe (use a VS command prompt to get it on the PATH) on the executable to ensure the architecture is what you expect: `dumpbin.exe /headers foo.exe`.  In the file header output, you should see a "machine" value of "x86" or "x64".  In the optional header output, you should see a magic of "PE32" (for x86) or "PE32+" (for x64).

The next step is to run the appropriate dependency walker, available at [www.dependencywalker.com](http://www.dependencywalker.com), depending on the architecture (x86 or x64) of the executable.  This tool should tell you if it locates a dependency on the search paths that is not of the same architecture.

If dependency walker finds a problem, the fix would then be to replace the offending library with a library of the same architecture or ensure the correct library is located before the incorrect library based on search paths.

Comment: Thanks for the tracking method.
Dumpbin reports a machine value of x86, and a magic of PE32.

Dependency walker reports that ZLIB1.dll for x64 architecture is loaded. How come? To be honest, I don't even know what this dll is for. 
May be you could shed a light on this?
Thanks.

Comment: I forgot, ZLIB1.dll (x64) is requested by LIBFREETYPE-6.dll (x86), accordign to what I see [and understand] in Dependency Walker.

Comment: Where is zlib1.dll currently installed to?  Try replacing it with a 32-bit version and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: It was in ProgramFiles/Intel/Wifi/bin.
Obviously replacing it with a 32-bit version did the trick.
But I would have liked to know why this dll was asked for!
Anyway, at least Dependency Walker pointed out the culprit. Then thanks!

Comment: My guess is that this is just a normal dependency of something your application depends on.  An installer likely modified the PATH to point at this directory (%ProgramFiles% is for 64-bit software; %ProgramFiles(x86)% is for 32-bit software) and you just happen to pick up the 64-bit version.  You probably don't want to replace this library with the 32-bit version, as it will likely break something that depends on it.  Instead, I'd just copy the 32-bit version local to your application.  Shouldn't be anything to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your informations. I copied it locally, this is the safest indeed.