# Cannot compile on 64 bit configuration in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a new c++ project in Visual Studio 2015.
I can compile perfectly in 32 bit configuration but when I change the configuration to 64 bit, compilation crashes with a dialogue box showing message "Microsoft c/c++ Compiler Driver has stopped working"

This is the error showing in the logs

Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741701.

I tried repairing and reinstalling VS several times but did no good to me.
This the behaviour of any file I am trying to compile. Projects which were working on Visual Studio 2013 are now not compilable.
Please help. I am stuck in this issue for weeks

EDIT: I found that the compiler used in 64 is x86_amd64\cl.exe, if this means anything to you
EDIT: I tried to compile using x86_amd64\cl.exe through command line and it succeeded there

Comment: Post repro code. Something we call a [MCVE].

Comment: Check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648621/c-sdl-native-has-exited-with-code-1073741701-0xc000007b and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372565/runtime-error-dll-loading-with-win32-applications-on-x64-system-while-compili

Comment: Make sure you've cleaned your sources entirely (clean grab it from source control). This could be caused by the compiler choking on accessing corrupted files which already exist.

Comment: but this error happens on every new project

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038660/visual-studio-2013-cl-exe-exited-with-code-1073741515 " -1073741515 == 0xC0000135 == STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: but my error code is 1073741701. I read it indicates corrupted image. That is  why I tried installing multiple times.

Comment: You need to raise an issue with Microsoft. Also try a clean install of the OS.

Comment: I would suggest to reinstall Windows and then install Visual Studio. I had some different complicated troubles with VS and 4x reinstall did not help. Reinstalling system + VS helped.